# Gradle is stuck due to locks when building a specific android project

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have recently upgraded my mac-os to Mojave, we upgraded gradle wrapper for our Android Project to

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.6-all.zip

Java Version:

```
java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)
```

I have the following config for gradle (gradle.properties):

```
org.gradle.daemon=true
org.gradle.configureondemand=true
org.gradle.parallel=true
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2560M
```

and gradle is stuck at this step for at least 4-5 minutes when building from command line.

```
15:26:04.001 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Apply plugin com.google.gms.google-services to project ':app'' started
15:26:04.072 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Apply plugin com.google.gms.google-services to project ':app''
15:26:04.073 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Completing Build operation 'Apply script build.gradle to project ':app''
15:26:04.074 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor] Timing: Running the build script took 3.053 secs
15:26:04.076 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.Project] Parsing the SDK, no caching allowed
15:26:06.633 [null] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager]
15:26:06.633 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 17179869184, Free: 8446320640}
15:26:06.633 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 17179869184, Free: 8446320640}
15:26:06.634 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 15435038720, Committed: 412090368}
15:26:08.638 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
15:26:08.641 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:08.641 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:08.641 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:08.641 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:08.641 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:08.642 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:11.629 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 17179869184, Free: 8340094976}
15:26:11.629 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 17179869184, Free: 8340094976}
15:26:11.629 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 15435038720, Committed: 527433728}
15:26:16.633 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 17179869184, Free: 8315412480}
15:26:16.633 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 17179869184, Free: 8315412480}
15:26:16.633 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 15435038720, Committed: 591921152}
15:26:18.638 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
15:26:18.638 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:18.638 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:18.639 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:18.639 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:18.639 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:18.639 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:21.628 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 17179869184, Free: 8274833408}
15:26:21.628 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 17179869184, Free: 8274833408}
15:26:21.628 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 15435038720, Committed: 594018304}
15:26:26.630 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 17179869184, Free: 8236703744}
15:26:26.630 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 17179869184, Free: 8236703744}
15:26:26.630 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 15435038720, Committed: 656408576}
15:26:28.633 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.Daemon] DaemonExpirationPeriodicCheck running
15:26:28.634 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:28.634 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:28.634 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:28.634 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Waiting to acquire shared lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:28.634 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Lock acquired on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:28.634 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on daemon addresses registry.
15:26:31.628 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 17179869184, Free: 8252747776}
15:26:31.628 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 17179869184, Free: 8252747776}
15:26:31.628 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 15435038720, Committed: 696254464}
15:26:36.631 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting OS memory status event {Total: 17179869184, Free: 8158916608}
15:26:36.631 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.LowMemoryDaemonExpirationStrategy] Received memory status update: {Total: 17179869184, Free: 8158916608}
15:26:36.631 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.process.internal.health.memory.MemoryManager] Emitting JVM memory status event {Maximum: 15435038720, Committed: 735051776}
```

**Someone reported it here, but they say that's normal, I don't see it normal, as i happens only to me and another colelague in the team, even for my personal Mac. for the same project, same Java version it doesn't happen**

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/5525

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: @Sagar got any solution to this problem.

Comment: @Rameshbabu can you post your answer?